# What are usability implications of using magic link/password-less only login for older users?

Tags: login, password

The audience of the product tends to be older (50+) so it is very likely that it would be their first time using an app that is password-less login only. We fear this might be confusing for this user group. Would you still recommend going for it or rather stay with something people know (standard password)? Is there any research on password-less logins for the older generation?

Thanks!

Comment: It probably depends on what information is exposed behind authentication. Is it feasible to quickly test this with a few of your users?

Comment: Not really feasible right now. There are other things to test that are more important. We just need to decide on one way or the other for the re-launch, we can then test the alternative later on.

Comment: You're either going to be testing this before launching, or after. One is much cheaper.